Unable to Access req.user in Backend and Frontend After Successful Login
I'm working on a project where users can log in and view/edit data based on their role (Admin or regular user). After successful login, a JWT is generated and sent to the frontend, but I can't seem to access the req.user in either the backend or frontend properly.
Backend Setup
In my backend, I use JWT for authentication. When a user logs in, a token is generated, and I attach it to the cookies.
Here's my backend login route:
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { usernameOrEmail, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [{ email: usernameOrEmail }, { username: usernameOrEmail }]
            }
        });

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid username or email' });
        }

        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isMatch) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid password' });
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({
            id: user.id,
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            role: user.role,
        }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '2h' });

        res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true });
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Login successful',
            token,
            user: {
                id: user.id,
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email,
                role: user.role,
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
    }
});

Here's my middleware for verifying the token:
const authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.token; // Extract JWT token from cookies

    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Access denied. No token provided.' });
    }

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        req.user = decoded;  // Attach user data to req.user
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Invalid token.' });
    }
};

Frontend Setup (on a different port)
After login, I'm trying to fetch the user data in the frontend and display admin-specific links (e.g., edit brands).
Here’s the frontend login logic:
async function loginUser(usernameOrEmail, password) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ usernameOrEmail, password }),
            credentials: 'include'
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            const decodedToken = jwt_decode(data.token);
            const role = decodedToken.role;

            if (role === 'Admin') {
                window.location.href = '/brands/edit';
            } else {
                window.location.href = '/profile';
            }
        } else {
            alert('Login failed');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during login:', error);
        alert('Login failed: ' + error.message);
    }
}

And I'm trying to fetch the user data like this:
async function fetchUser() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user', {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',  // Include the cookie with the token
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            return data.user;
        } else {
            console.log('Failed to fetch user data');
            return null;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
        return null;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
    const user = await fetchUser();
    if (user && user.role === 'Admin') {
        console.log('Admin user:', user);
        document.getElementById('admin-links').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        console.log('Non-admin or guest user:', user);
    }
}); 

Problem
Even after the login is successful (verified by inspecting the token in the browser's Application tab), the req.user remains undefined in both the frontend and backend. I can see the token and its payload in the browser, but when I try to access protected routes or display admin-specific content, it doesn't recognize the user.
In the backend, req.user is undefined in the route that requires user authentication, and in the frontend, fetchUser() always returns null.
I've confirmed that the token is being set in the cookies, and it contains the correct user data.
Questions:
Why is req.user undefined in the backend even though the token is being set and sent in the cookies?
Why is fetchUser() returning null or failing to fetch the logged-in user on the frontend?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
